# Sin resultado con Query String dinamico Rest-PHP

Tags: php, json, rest

Al hacer la siguiente petición a una API Rest

```
$response = $this->client->request('GET',$this->urlReports, [
                 'headers' => $header,
                 'query' => ['messageId' => '1b15a714-ac04-4c48-bbc5-8b9a747e8d84']
```

me retorna la información que requiero, pero si la realizo así de manera dinámica

```
$response = $this->client->request('GET',$this->urlReports, [
                 'headers' => $header,
                 'query' => ['messageId' => $messageId]
```

no me retorna nada como si no tomara el formato o no se, es de aclarar que **$messageId** si tiene el id que necesito consultar osea que no esta vació, ya lo he verificado.

Estoy utilizando la librería Guzzle 6 para peticiones http

Comment: De donde obtienes $messageId?

Comment: De cuando envió el mensaje la API me retorna un json como respuesta del cual obtengo el messageId este es el proceso completo                                                   $body = $response->getBody();
    $responseJson = $body->getContents();
    $result = json_decode($responseJson) ;                                               $messageId = $result->messages[0]->messageId;